# Linux Ubuntu BusyBox shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My Linux (Ubuntu machine) doesn't boot anymore. It drops to this BusyBox shell.

I do not know where to start tracing the issue because it does not display any main error.

This is all that it displays on the screen

```
Begin: Waiting for root file system... Begin: Running /scripts/local-block done. done.
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cdline)
- Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; 1s /dev)
ALERT! UUID=24f6627-79b2-499e-aec1-b7fd836e0d69 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell. (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands. 
(initramfs)
```

Comment: The important line is `ALERT! UUID=24f6627-79b2-499e-aec1-b7fd836e0d69 does not exist`. You don't have a boot disk